# How to change email body format to HTML from an Outlook VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I'm coding an Outlook add-in, that is written using Visual Studio and VSTO, that can automatically change the format of outbound emails to HTML:

[image]

I'd doing the following:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Add event handler for when emails are sent out
    this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(onItemSend);
}

private void onItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    //Called when email is sent
    Outlook.MailItem objMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

    //Set message format as HTML
    objMailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
}
```

I'm noticing that my `onItemSend` is called, and if the original email that is being sent was composed as plain-text, that email still arives at the destination as plain-text in despite of my change there. I even tried reading `objMailItem.BodyFormat` back and it says `olFormatHTML`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same results in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: Is this the case https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/always-send-outlook-emails-plain-text-format-specific-contacts/ ?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev:  I don't know why it doesn't work. I gave up on this method. Instead I'm trying to change message format when the user clicks Reply/Forward.

Comment: Go to File-> Outlook-Option -> Mail Tab and select Compose message in this format there is an option for HTML, Plain Text

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah that is for new messages. If your message already arrived as plaintext and you went to reply to it in HTML format this setting won't work.

Comment: I have developed similar type of plugin for outlook 2010 and above. I have changed formating and it was working for all emails. there need to write more code related to storing property and updating body

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah: well, sure. Why don't you show how it's done then.

Comment: there was several lines of code I will post later

Comment: The same thing just happened to me, I even didn't change the body format and in the variable inspector it is visible that it is 2 (HTML). Still, my Thunderbird client is receiving plain text with rtf attachment

Comment: Also make sure that you are not adding any user properties to your email, because that will force TNEF on it!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the `BodyFormat` property, you need to set the correct HTML markup for your message body - the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody) property sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.